# Scala - Option.getOrElse() "type erasure"?

Tags: scala, type-erasure, scala-option

I am trying to use the `Option.getOrElse()` method but it returns etiher `Any` or `ScalaObject` instead of an instance of the correct class that the `Option` was parametrized with. I can't find any mention about this problem and it does not seem like it should be there. What am I doing wrong?

```
class MyClass {

  def isOk = true

}

val myVal = Some(new MyClass) // :Option[MyClass]

val check = myVal.getOrElse(false).isOk
```

Can't call the `isOk` method because it tries calling it upon `Any`.

Comment: Type "erasure" is not the problem here, rather, it is that the extreme expressive power that comes with subtyping is sometimes too lenient to catch your mistakes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are trying to call method `isOk` on base class of `MyClass` and `Boolean` (`Any`).

Try this:

```
scala> class MyClass(b: Boolean) { def isOk = b }
defined class MyClass

scala> val myVal = Some(new MyClass(true))
myVal: Some[MyClass] = Some(MyClass@35d56bbe)

scala> myVal.map{_.isOk}.getOrElse(false)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> myVal.getOrElse(new MyClass(false)).isOk
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: I think that the `map (_.isOk)` approach is what noncom is actually trying to do.

Answer (score 8):

Works as designed. This expression:

```
myVal.getOrElse(false)
```

returns either unwrapped `MyClass` instance or (if `Option` is actually `None`) - `false`. The only common type of `MyClass` and `Boolean` is... `Any`. And this is what you are seeing.

In order for this to work you must return something compatible with `MyClass` from `getOrElse()`:

```
myVal.getOrElse(new MyClass).isOk
```

Or maybe you want to implement *null-object* pattern:

```
object MyClass {
  val Empty = new MyClass
}

myVal.getOrElse(MyClass.Empty).isOk
```

Comment: If you return a new `MyClass` then the expression will always be true

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: of course, it is about general idea (and that's why I am mentioning about null-object pattern - but it suffers the same problem). In fact I think `map (_.isOk)` is actually what OP wants.

Answer (score 6):

You are applying getOrElse in a Option[MyClass] with Boolean, so, their common superclass is Any.

You should pattern match:

```
val check = myVal match {
  case Some(c) => c.isOk
  case None => false
}
```

Comment: +1 I always encourage pattern matching when it comes to dealing with Options, because it makes everything you could possibly do with them very simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `getOrElse` on an `Option[MyClass]`. You're passing a `Boolean` as a parameter to `getOrElse`. What happens is that Scala is translating the option to an `Option[Any]`, because `Any` is the most specific common type of `MyClass` and `Boolean`.

Pass a `MyClass` (or a subclass of `MyClass`) to `getOrElse` instead of `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Because your getOrElse could return false, the common type for MyClass and false is Any.

Answer (score 1):

Jhonny Everson is right. Pattern matching is the answer. In this case, the pattern in his answer is equivalent to `exists`

```
scala> Some(new MyClass) :: None :: Nil map(_.exists(_.isOK))
res12: List[Boolean] = List(true, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

So you've got an `Option[A]`, and a function `A => B`, and a default `B` for when the Optional value is `None`, and you want to end up with a `B`. (In your case, `A` is `MyClass` and `B` is `Boolean`).

Being a Haskeller, the first thing I think to do is hoogle. Recall that in Haskell, `Option` is called `Maybe`. So we [hoogle `Maybe a -> (a -> b) -> b -> b`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Maybe+a+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+b+-%3E+b), and the top hit is `maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b`, which does exactly what we want.

```
data MyClass = MyClass { isOK :: Bool }
newMyClass = MyClass { isOK = true }

myVal = newMyClass
check = maybe False isOK myVal
```

Well that's well and good, but what about Scala? Well, the Scala equivalent to hoogle is [Scalex](http://scalex.org/). I searched Scalex for `Option[A] => B => (A => B) => B`, but to no avail. So instead, let's check out how the `maybe` function was implemented in Haskell. You can find the source by following the appropriate links from hoogle.

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
maybe n _ Nothing  = n
maybe _ f (Just x) = f x
```

Seems easy enough to translate into Scala

```
def option[A, B](opt: Option[A])(n: B)(f: A => B) = opt match {
  case None => n
  case Some(x) => f(x)
}
```

This can then be used like so:

```
val check = option(myVal)(false)(_.isOK)
```

You'll have to ask people more expert in Scala than I if you want to do this with less currying or by pimping the Option class, but notice how this basically boils down to the pattern matching that Jhonny Everson suggested.